# PHP Connect To Amazon Using Pem

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2

This question seems to have no right answer. I'm trying to connect to an instance on Amazon using a pem file, but I keey getting:

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for ubuntu using public key: Invalid public key
```

The PEM files do not have public key so I am extracting the public key from the private key. Here is a sample of my code:

```
protected function _createServerSession($host, $user, $password = null, $options = array()) {

        $defaults = array('port' => 22, 'public_key_file' => '', 'private_key_file' => '', 'key_pass_phrase' => null, 'authentication_method' => 'password', 'pem_file' => null);
        $options += $defaults;

        $methods = array(
            'kex' => 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 
            'client_to_server' => array(
                'crypt' => '3des-cbc', 'comp' => 'none'
            ), 
            'server_to_client' => array(
                'crypt' => 'aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc', 
                'comp' => 'none')
        );

        $connection = ssh2_connect($host, $options['port'], $methods);

        if ($connection) {
            $this -> _connection = $connection;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Cannot connect to server');
        }

        $fingerprint = ssh2_fingerprint($this -> _connection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_MD5 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX);

        if ($options['authentication_method'] == 'pem') {

            //Get the public and private key from pem file
            $public_key_res = openssl_pkey_get_public($options['pem_file']);
            $private_key_res = openssl_pkey_get_private($options['pem_file']);

            //Get the private key
            if($private_key_res) {
                $private_key_array = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key_res);
                $private_key = $private_key_array['key'];
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Private key required to connect using pem');
            }

            //Get the public key public key. If it does not exist, get the public key from the private key
            if($private_key && !$public_key_res){
                $public_key_res = openssl_pkey_get_public($private_key);
                $public_key_array = openssl_pkey_get_details($public_key_res);
                $public_key = $public_key_array['key'];

            } else {
                throw new Exception('Public key required to connect using pem');
            }

            //Write the Keys Out To A File
            $private_key_file = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../tmp/tmp.key';
            $public_key_file = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../tmp/tmp';
            file_put_contents($private_key_file, $private_key);
            file_put_contents($public_key_file, $public_key);

            //Authentickate
            $authenticated = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $user, $public_key_file, $private_key_file);


            die();
        }
}
```

Has anyone succedded in connecting to Amazon through PHP using a PEM file? And if you have can you share how or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, The pem_file is being passed through as the entire file already read into memory.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```